# $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ is measurable iff $E^c$ is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am working on measurable sets on $(\mathbb{R},d_E)$. When I read the theorem - which is " $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ is measurable iff $E^c$ is measurable." -, then I came up with the idea following;

If I can prove the theorem then I can easily prove

•Every compact in $\mathbb{R}$ set is measurable

$ $     •   (For sub idea the Cantor set is measurable)

•Every closed set in $\mathbb{R}$ is measurable.

by using the theorem. **From now my knowledge includes**

**i)** Let $U$ is an $d_E$-open set then $U$ can be written by using disjoint intervals $\{I_n\}$ which are finite or countable sets and   $U= \bigcup_n I_n$ $\Rightarrow$ $m(U)=\sum_n m(I_n)$.

and

**ii)** Let $U$ and $V$ are $d_E$-open sets on $\mathbb{R}$

**$m(U)+m(V)=m(U \cup V) + m(U \cap V)$**

**iii)** $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ is a bounded set. $E$ can be measured iff $\lambda^*(E)=\lambda_*(E)$

Any guidances,tips  will help, thanks in advance

Comment: Um... measurable is a word which means the set is in the sigma Algebra. By definition complements are in the sigma algebra, so by definition every complement is measurable. That is not really a theorem.

Comment: There are many logically equivalent definitions of Lebesgue measurability (e.g. Caratheodory, approximation by open sets, etc.). Which are you using?

Comment: I am using approximation with open sets

Comment: It is unclear from your question what _specific_ question you would like answered. You would like help proving $E$ measurable iff $E^c$ measurable?

Comment: Yes, for proving $E$ is measurable iff $E^c$ measurable. I writed a bit long,  by doing this it may gone a bit complicated because of  don't wanting be a type "Please prove that I am waiting.", thanks in advance for you help